# blank page with Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I have a strong problem with the Facebook PHP SDK. Here it is.

1) On my personal server this works fine:

```
$me = $facebook->getSignedRequest(); 
print_r($me);
$user = $facebook->api('/me');
print_r($user);
```

while on another remote server (a Windows one btw) it doesn't. 
If if comment the 2 last lines, it does, but the `$facebook->api` call breaks my script and I get a blank page.

2) This bug seems CURL related since at some point I got this screenshot : http://www.thomasaussenac.com/harleytest/screenshot.png

Anyway, I really can't get a way to solve it!

---

I still have the same error and sometimes I get such a message on a blank page :

> Could not set cookie. Headers already sent.
>   Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information

But the fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt should be fine...

I don't understand at all, really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I was using a server Windows without Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error message mentiones a cookie problem, try this:

```
$output = '';

$me = $facebook->getSignedRequest(); 
$output .= print_r( $me, TRUE ); 

$user = $facebook->api('/me'); 
$output .= print_r( $user, TRUE );

echo $output;
```

Why? Because $facebook->api('/me'); might try to set a cookie. Unfortunately, a PHP application can't set a cookie, if some output has already been sent to the browser.

Thus, it might be wise to save all output in a variable and finally send the variable's contents to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This did not work. I still get a blank page. But a new clue : today, I turned on my computer and executed my script and it worked the first time and the second time (even if slower the second time)! Then after executing another page which also calls "$user = $facebook->api('/me');" I got a "Could not set cookie. Headers already sent. Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information" message and then when I came back to my original test script -> blank page...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a server configuration problem but I have no clue of what it could be...

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are using correct API & Secret key. Check whether CURL is enabled in your apache server or not (by phpinfo())

Comment: About the API & Secret key, yes I'm sure. About the CURL, I checked but I will double check.

Comment: On the phpinfo() it says : `cURL support - enabled | cURL Information - libcurl/7.16.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3` so I guess it's all good.